# Adding a viewbag (in place of actionname) in ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to call an actionlink using a viewbag.
I tried something like below, did not work..

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me!", @ViewBag.Link, "Home", new {@class = "button-big" })
```

Any ideas will be appreciated..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to cast `ViewBag.Link` into `string`

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me!", (string)ViewBag.Link, "Home", null, new {@class = "button-big" })
```

there is no overload as below see [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), which you are using

```
@Html.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object)
```

Thus use

```
@Html.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)
```